# Kineticjs Draggable doesn't work with -ms-transform

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've been trying to use Kineticjs 4.3.3. to create a graphical image and can be dragged across a parent div, but it will not work if the parent div has scalling set under its style properties ( example provided http://jsfiddle.net/kreavie/MZSE9/). Does anyone have any ideas how to get dragging to work when scalling is previously set?

Thanks,
krlib

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


 window.onload = function () {

        var par = document.getElementById('frame');
        var canvas = document.createElement('div');
        canvas.id = "canvas1";
        par.appendChild(canvas);


        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'canvas1',
            width: 500,
            height: 500
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var triangle = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            stroke: "red",
            strokeWidth: 4,
            points: [60, 100, 90, 100, 90, 140],
            draggable: true
        });

        layer.add(triangle);
        stage.add(layer);


    }
    </script>

</head>
<body >

     <div id="frame" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; -ms-transform: scale(0.420091);">
                  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/MZSE9/2/

Your object is local to the canvas element, not to another div in which you apply scaling.

if you want to scale an object, layer, or the entire stage just do:

```
 shape.setScale(xAmount, yAmount);
 stage.setScale(xAmount, yAmount);
 layer.setScale(xAmount, yAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the end what I'm trying to do is dynamically draw a canvas element to a document page. I will need to have the pixel coordinates and canvas size match that of the orinigal page size. So as a user zooms in and out of a document page, adds graphical markups, those markups can be retrieved later and reapplied to the document display at the exact document page coordinates inwhich they were originally drawn.

Comment: When canvas is transformed(rotated,scaled, or whatever), KineticJS does not respond to mouse event any more. It might be a bug unless it is intentional.

Comment: KineticJS currently requires that the container element is not scaled.  I'll have to put a bit more thought into this one.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their response.